# Threading Matlab Codes

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab

I'm developing a java code which makes use of certain code written in matlab via calling by jar file.

Since there are many functions to work on.. will be good to associate a separate thread in java, associated with each matlab function calling, because its an intense processing which requires considerable time of processing...

Which one will be better way to structure the code?
Using multiple threads or calling as simple function call?

Thanx in Advance.. :)

Comment: It sounds like you can trivially split the execution into multiple processes. If that is the case than this would be the easier approach. When you use different threads you have to worry about what part of memory is shared and what isn't and that (especially debugging it) can be a real pain. A more detailed answer would require that you explain your problem more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using the Parallel toolbox, multithreading does not work. Matlab executes its computations in a single thread and does not permit concurrent requests. Calls to your jar file will block until Matlab has finished executing the previous call.

The only way around this (other than the toolbox I mentioned) is to execute each function as a seperate process via `Runtime.exec()` and use RMI to communicate with the new process.